# rake assets:precompile not working always showing : read': No such file or directory - assets:precompile:all

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, ruby-1.9.3, sprockets

I am using ubuntu 64-bit machine using, rvm, ruby 1.9.3-p448 , rails 3.2.13
And am not able to precompile assets.
I used following commands but got same error always :-

1. rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
2. rake assets:precompile
3. bundle exec rake assets:precompile

> ```
>  mymachine:~/mymachine-rails/prod$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
> DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails
> ```
>
> 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See
>   the release notes for more on this:
>   http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released.
>   (called from  at
>   /home/mymachine/mymachine-rails/prod/Rakefile:7)
>       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails
>   4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See
>   the release notes for more on this:
>   http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released.
>   (called from  at
>   /home/mymachine/mymachine-rails/prod/Rakefile:7)
>       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails
>   4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See
>   the release notes for more on this:
>   http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released.
>   (called from  at
>   /home/mymachine/mymachine-rails/prod/Rakefile:7)
>       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails
>   4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See
>   the release notes for more on this:
>   http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released.
>   (called from  at
>   /home/mymachine/mymachine-rails/prod/Rakefile:7)
>       ** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
>       ** Execute assets:precompile
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/bin/ruby_executable_hooks
>   assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:14:in
>   `read': No such file or directory - assets:precompile:all
>   (Errno::ENOENT)
>         from /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:14:in`
>   '
>       rake aborted!
>       Command failed with status (1): [/home/mymachine/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/...]
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:55:in
>   `block in create_shell_runner'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in`
>   call'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in
>   `sh'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in`sh'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:82:in
>   `ruby'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in`ruby'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in`invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in`
>   call'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in
>   `block in execute'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in`
>   each'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in
>   `execute'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in`
>   block in invoke_with_call_chain'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in
>   `mon_synchronize'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in`
>   invoke_with_call_chain'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in
>   `invoke'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in`
>   invoke_task'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in
>   `block (2 levels) in top_level'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in`
>   each'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in
>   `block in top_level'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in`
>   run_with_threads'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in
>   `top_level'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in`
>   block in run'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in
>   `standard_exception_handling'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in`
>   run'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/bin/rake:19:in`load'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:14:in`
>   eval'
>       /home/mymachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@mymachine/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:14:in
>   `'
>       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile

**Gems List** :-

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.13)
actionpack (3.2.13)
activemodel (3.2.13)
activerecord (3.2.13)
activeresource (3.2.13)
activesupport (3.2.13)
acts-as-taggable-on (2.4.1)
acts_as_paranoid (0.4.2)
angularjs-rails (1.0.7)
arel (3.0.2)
bcrypt-ruby (3.1.1)
browser (0.2.0)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
cancan (1.6.10)
chronic (0.9.1)
climate_control (0.0.3)
cocaine (0.5.1)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
columnize (0.3.6)
commonjs (0.2.6)
couchrest (1.1.3)
couchrest_model (1.1.2)
daemons (1.1.9)
debugger (1.6.1)
debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.2.3)
devise (3.0.0)
em-synchrony (1.0.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (1.0.3)
execjs (1.4.0)
executable-hooks (1.2.2)
faraday (0.8.7)
faye-websocket (0.6.2)
hashie (2.0.5)
hike (1.2.3)
hiredis (0.4.5)
httpauth (0.2.0)
i18n (0.6.1)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (3.0.4)
jquery-ui-rails (4.0.4)
json (1.7.7)
jwt (0.1.8)
less (2.3.2)
less-rails (2.3.3)
libv8 (3.16.14.3 x86_64-linux, 3.11.8.17 x86_64-linux)
localtunnel (0.3)
magic_multi_connections (1.2.1)
mail (2.5.4)
masonry-rails (0.2.0)
mime-types (1.23)
mini_portile (0.5.1)
multi_json (1.7.7)
multipart-post (1.2.0)
mysql2 (0.3.13)
net-ssh (2.6.8)
net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
nokogiri (1.6.0)
oauth (0.4.7)
oauth2 (0.8.1)
omniauth (1.1.4)
omniauth-facebook (1.4.1)
omniauth-google-oauth2 (0.2.0)
omniauth-linkedin-oauth2 (0.0.2)
omniauth-oauth (1.0.1)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1)
omniauth-twitter (1.0.0)
orm_adapter (0.4.0)
paperclip (3.5.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-offline (0.6.4)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.13)
railties (3.2.13)
rake (10.1.0)
rb-readline (0.4.2)
rdoc (3.12.2)
redis (3.0.4)
ref (1.0.5)
rest-client (1.6.7)
rsolr (1.0.9)
rubygems-bundler (1.3.2)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
sass (3.2.9)
sass-rails (3.2.6)
sprockets (2.2.2)
swipe-rails (0.0.5)
therubyracer (0.12.0, 0.11.4)
thin (1.5.1)
thor (0.18.1)
tilt (1.4.1)
time_diff (0.3.0)
treetop (1.4.14)
twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.7)
tzinfo (0.3.37)
uglifier (2.1.2)
warden (1.2.3)
websocket-driver (0.2.1)
websocket-rails (0.4.9)
whenever (0.8.4)
will_paginate (3.0.4)
```

Comment: Can you try the same by changing the rake gem version to a lower version, either `0.9.6` or `0.9.2.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be an RVM quirk. I ran into this using rvm + ruby 2.0.0-p247 and this worked for me:

```
rvm ruby-2.0.0-p247@global do gem install executable-hooks
```